# Prevent JSON file from becoming part of chunk.js/app.js when I build my vue app

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I have a JSON file that I included in my vue app. But the problem is that when I build the app, the JSON file disappears and becomes a part from a js file.
How can I keep it as a JSON file after build, since I want to manipulate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Vue CLI 3, you can place your static files in `public` directory and reference them by absolute paths.

For more information you can visit the CLI [documents](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder).

---

## Update

1. Place your JSON file in `public` directory
2. Import **axios** or any similar tools you use for AJAX calls.
3. You need a `.env` file in your project root. And store your base url in `BASE_URL` variable. ([Read More!](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html))
4. Add a data property containing your base URL:

   ```
   data() {
       return {
           baseUrl: process.env.BASE_URL,
       }
   },
   ```
5. And then you can access you JSON value with an ajax call:

   ```
       axios.get(this.baseUrl + 'test.json').then(response => {
           console.log(response);
       })
   ```

Comment: I tried this but It didn't work : import jsonFile from '${baseUrl}details.json'
How should it be ?

Comment: @Mrkinix I have updated my answer with more details. Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to configure the [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) option.

Comment: Where should I place my Json file then, and how can I refer to it?